# Shopify and Private Applications

Tags: c#, jquery, oauth, oauth-2.0, shopify

I have created a private app for use on my website (The idea is the website will act as the front end using shopify's api to connect to the store).
When I create the application, if I edit it there is an example url which looks like this:

> > https://926b44aa1af222f2089ffa4988bc146b:49a28c7ccfa3b29b2a9af8019b2723cc@kudos-6.myshopify.com/admin/products.json

f you click that link, you can see the products I have set up.
Now, if I take that URL and put it into my website using jQuery $.get, I get an error stating Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password which is really infuriating as you can imaging.

I tried to add a header using the ApiPassword which looks like this:

"X-Shopify-Access-Token": "49a28c7ccfa3b29b2a9af8019b2723cc"

But I get the same error.
Now this is probably due to not allowing cross origin headers, etc. So I created a function in c#:

```
public string Get()
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        return wc.DownloadString("https://926b44aa1af222f2089ffa4988bc146b:49a28c7ccfa3b29b2a9af8019b2723cc@kudos-6.myshopify.com/admin/products.json");
    }
}
```

Which I expected to work, but it doesn't. I get the same error.
So I tried:

```
public string Get()
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "926b44aa1af222f2089ffa4988bc146b");

        return wc.DownloadString("https://926b44aa1af222f2089ffa4988bc146b:49a28c7ccfa3b29b2a9af8019b2723cc@kudos-6.myshopify.com/admin/products.json");
    }
}
```

and guess what, I get the same error.
So I tried using the secret:

```
public string Get()
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "e63081c23cd05b64205dbdb670d60241");

        return wc.DownloadString("https://926b44aa1af222f2089ffa4988bc146b:49a28c7ccfa3b29b2a9af8019b2723cc@kudos-6.myshopify.com/admin/products.json");
    }
}
```

Same error.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for anyone else having this problem, here is the solution:

First, add these lines to your **WebApiConfig**:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Then, use your **Api password** as the **access token** like this:

```
public string Get()
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "49a28c7ccfa3b29b2a9af8019b2723cc");

        return wc.DownloadString("https://kudos-6.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json");
    }
}
```

and that is it. If you do it like that, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and fixed it by adding a header information.. I am accessing API through windows service..

So I have created  a custom app in Shopify and
I was getting authentication error as I was only passing in API Key and APi password.
You need to attach Admin API token to the header and also use API key and API password.

```
 var restSharpClient = new RestClient(_shopifyBaseStoreURL);

  restSharpClient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_privateAppAPIKey, _privateAppPassword);

  restSharpClient.AddDefaultHeader("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "shpXXXX");

I also added in.when making a GET / PUT request..

restSharpRequest.Method = Method.GET;

restSharpRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

restSharpRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

restSharpRequest.AddHeader("X - Shopify - Access - Token", "shxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve products using jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://yourshop.myshopify.com/products.json',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

Comment: you can't do this. You need some authentication or something.

Comment: @r3plica I believe you can. Give it a try :)

Comment: I did and I got this error : Refused to execute script from 'https://kudos-6.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?callback=jQuery1102044428987987339497_1422392486161&_=1422392486162' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: @r3plica Right, it wouldn't work for orders. However, it does for fetching products, cart info and certain other kinds of data.

Comment: same thing: Refused to execute script from 'https://kudos-6.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?callback=jQuery110207135208873078227_1422394691812&_=1422394691813' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: @r3plica With these URLs, there is no `/admin` piece. For example, in your case you could use `https://kudos-6.myshopify.com/products.json`

Answer (score -2):

You should STOP and quit this pattern while you are ahead. Do you not see the folly of putting your API token with access to your shop **in a public website**? There is nothing stopping any Tom, Dick or Jane from molesting your shop and ruining your e-commerce day.

Instead, make yourself a front-end that uses an App Proxy to access your backend goods. At least that is secure, and ensures no one can mess with your shop.

Comment: it's a test site, so they can't ruin anything

Comment: So if you wonder if your gun works, do you load it, point it at your friend and try it out?

Comment: No, I put blanks in it and fire it to make sure that it actually fires. The reason I included all the API keys, etc, was so people could actually play with it, if they had the time or actually want to.

Comment: right.. but once you get past the fact that it fires blanks, when you do indeed put in real bullets, you will be wasting your real friends. Hence my point. Try playing with nerf balls instead. You both have fun, and no one gets hurt!

Comment: No, once I have it working (as now I do). I delete the private app and recreate it, thus nullifying all the api access tokens, etc.